# Failed close-audit on mysql installation/initialization issue

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, disputed-review-audits

I am relatively new to the close vote queue and just failed an audit regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031821/error-during-installation-database-initialization-failed) question.

Am I wrong in regarding it as belonging on SuperUser? We have of course many `sql` questions on the site but does that render the database initialisation procedure as on-topic? I am especially confused since it has received a good amount of upvotes despite its short existence.

Comment: Audits are chosen automatically. Since that question got 8 (!!!) upvotes and no downvotes, it was chosen as "known good question", so you failed by saying it should be closed. As long as it receives a single down-vote, it will removed of the audit pool. If you think the question is not useful, you can downvote it yourself outside of the review queue.

Comment: You can also vote to close outside of the review queue, which I think would also remove the post from the audit pool.

Comment: @yivi thanks for the response, I am aware of that but I would like to clarify if my perception of the on/off topic of such questions is correct or not

Comment: Personally, I believe the question _may_ be on-topic in Server Fault, and off-topic here in SO.

Comment: I actually feel bad about the migration vote, since I guess the question is also poor for SF, even if may be on-topic there.

Comment: Would be kinda nice if you we could dump these kind of "installer failed" questions onto another web site.  But no, as long as a question like this gets 8 helpful votes then you know that a lot of programmers have this problem.  Also the basic way to pass an audit like this, be careful with content that is appreciated that much.  Very ugly, yet again, that somebody's failed audit produces so many downvotes.  My daily prayers that one of my posts doesn't get selected for an audit have been working so far.

Answer (score 2):

I just cast the final close vote on this question, it was quite blatantly a software configuration issue and off topic for stack overflow, in my opinion.

"Known good" Audits are chosen automatically from posts that are:

- Upvoted with no downvotes recently
- Have at least a certain score
- Have no active close votes and have never been closed

Which fit until now for this post. You can remove any audit you disagree with from the pool yourself by downvoting or close voting it yourself.